# Trying to update user points every X, sets all their points to undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I'm currently trying to update all user points every 1 minute (currently at 5 seconds for testing purposes), when I try to run it, it gets all the users, but then it sets their points to undefined.

```
  setInterval(async function () {
    var uPoints;
    await db.each("SELECT points points, id id FROM users", function (err, row) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      var u;
      for (u in client.users.array()) {
        uPoints = row.points + 10;
      }
    });
    var u, user;
    for (u in client.users.array()) {
      user = client.users.array()[u];
      tools.setPoints(uPoints, user.id.toString());
      console.log('Updated ' + user.id.toString() + ' to ' + uPoints);
    }
  }, 5000);
});
```

tools.setPoints

```
module.exports.setPoints = function (amnt, id) {
  db.run('UPDATE users SET points = ? WHERE id = ?', amnt, id);
}
```

Comment: I now have this https://hastebin.com/okaxirizay.js which gets all their points right, but it only grabs one user and it doesn't add +10 to their points at all. I'm at a loss and could use some help

Answer (score 0):

The update is executed before or in parallel with the SELECT.

You can fix that if you move the UPDATE inside the callback like so:

```
setInterval(async function () {
    var uPoints;
    await db.each("SELECT points points, id id FROM users", function (err, row) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      var u;
      for (u in client.users.array()) {
        uPoints = row.points + 10;
      }
      var user;
      for (u in client.users.array()) {
        user = client.users.array()[u];
        tools.setPoints(uPoints, user.id.toString());
        console.log('Updated ' + user.id.toString() + ' to ' + uPoints);
      }
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

---

I'm not sure what DB client you are using but generally, you don't want to mix await with callbacks.
You either want to have:

`const rows = await db.each("SELECT points points, id id FROM users");`

or

`db.each("SELECT points points, id id FROM users", function (err, rows) {..});`

You should check if your db client supports async/await or you can use promisify.

Comment: I've came to this solution before, but what it does is just create a new problem. All the users points are being updated to the same amount. If a user, let's say loses 10 points, 5 seconds later his points will be the same as everyone else.

Comment: This is another problem. Your uPoints variable is a single integer and you update every user with the same amount every time. You might want to check this code: `for (u in client.users.array()) { uPoints = row.points + 10; }` This will iterate all users and set uPoints to the last user's points + 10. and update all users with the same value. You may want to consider changing uPoints to Array/Object/Map rather than single integer that you update all users with.

Comment: I updated the code, it now returns undefined again. https://hastebin.com/sepizemebe.js